# How can I detect "excessive spaces" in a string?

Tags: string, lua

I'm making a simple android game in Lua, and in one of its steps to set the game is set an word (or sentence; basically, a string) input by the player. The "word" may have spaces, but I want to forbid the player to input a string with two or more spaces in a row, like `"fly    bird"`.

I tried using `string.match(word, "  ")`, `string.match(word, "%s%s")`
and `string.match(word, "%s+%s+")` and none of these worked, and somehow, the last one always "detect" double space, no matter if it has or not spaces.

What can I do to detect if there are multiple spaces in a row in a string? (Just detect, not replace, so I can send a warning message to the player.)

Comment: either of these should've worked.  post a minimal code that shows the failure, maybe there's something about how you're checking the return values. also, `find()` might be a better tool.

Comment: I was using this in an if statement with several other conditions. The code was something like `if( word == nil or word == '' or string.match(word, "!") or string.match(word, "%s%s") then    
invalidWordWarningMessage()  
else`

Comment: Well, code you typed should work. Looks like bug hides somewhere else. Have you tried to `print(word)` before this `if` statement? Maybe, it isn't what you expect it to be? Either way, consider using `find()` instead of `match()` - more natural in your case.

Comment: Well, the problem wasn't in the input of the string, cause when the word didn't have any of these matches (I was not verifying for multiple spaces), the program was supposed to print the word to the player, and it was working normally.

Answer (score 3):

If its exactly two spaces you are interested in, simply use `find`

```
word:find('  ')
```

It will return range of first occurrence of two consecutive spaces.

Comment: @rpattiso, yeah, thanks!! How on earth did I made that typo O_o

Comment: `word:find('  +')` might be a better fit, to match two *or more* spaces. (edit: Oddly it won't let me put two spaces in a row in a comment - that's not a typo)

Comment: In that case use '%s+'. More verbose

Comment: Careful, though, of the difference between `'%s+'` and `'%s%s+'` - the first matches one or more spaces, which is unintended behavior here.

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @nkorth, why? Won't it find space followed by 1 or more spaces?

Comment: @Sergii The `+` operator means "match the previous character/class one or more times".

Comment: @rpattiso @nkorth, well, it won't - `+` means exactly "match the previous character/class one or more times". So, we have one space %s, followed be at least one more space %s+. Like %s and %s+ -> %s%s+. '+' here affects only the second %s, it doesn't matters, what comes before it. This construct will detect "  " (twice), "   " (trice), "     "(n-ce), but not " " (once). I've just tried it in Lua 5.2.3

Comment: @Sergii It is somewhat counterintuitive - the operator doesn't signify an *additional* match, it just modifies how the previous character is matched. I tested it myself, and `%s+` did in fact match on a string that contained only a single space. (Always test for failure as well as success!)

Comment: @rpattiso It will. But if you try x:find"%s%s+" - it won't

Comment: @nkorth %s+ - one or more spaces (at least one). %s - exactly one. %s%s - exactly one followed by exactly one (exactly two). %s%s+ - exactly one followed by at least one (two or more)

Comment: @nkorth I'm sorry, my fault - I misunderstood your second comment in this conversation. You meant find('  +') - two spaces, right?

Comment: Its not your fault, the fact that extra spaces are stripped out of comments is at fault. `"   "`

Answer (score 0):

```
input = input:gsub("%s+", " ")
```

The above code should take the input and remove all excessive spacing and replace it with just 1 space.